# OBJLoader not loading Structure.IO model files in Three.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, objloader

I have the Structure.IO sensor which generates OBJ+MTL models that are correctly loaded into 3D editors (Blender, Cinema4D), but they are not showing in three.js. I've checked the loaded object and it has geometry and material that seems to be correct, but still it shows nothing when I add it to the scene.

Here you have the model I'm trying to use:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Hv0HwLV830a2cwWFpZMEpKNlU/view

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have lights in your scene?

Comment: Check your model's uvs; some are negative.

Comment: the model was generated by the scanner... but I have to say that it used to work with the OBJMTLLoader (rev71), after I upgraded to rev85 is stopped working... :(

Comment: also, my scene looks fine and I have lights... 
do I need to rollback the upgrade to make it work?